# How to fix keyboard above content on android (manifest.json)

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to setup my site to open as an app when people add it to their homepage on mobile but it's not working as expected when I have input fields. When the keyboard shows up it stays above the content, it doesn't get resized. It happens only when using via a shortcut on the phone homescreen.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "author": "My Name",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "description": "App",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://192.168.26.183:8080/img/web-app.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "App",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "short_name": "App",
  "start_url": "https://192.168.26.183:8080/",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "version": "0.1"
}
```

This is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <!-- Ask user to add to home screen -->
 <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body,
  html {
   height: 100%;
  }
  .teste {
   height: calc(100% - 10px);
   width: 100%;
   content: '';
   background-color: red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="teste"></div>
 <input type="text" id="texteeee">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is not manifest issue

Comment: add some code to get more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap all your content in container with `position: absolute;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- Ask user to add to home screen -->
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body,
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
            .wrapper {
              position: absolute;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              overflow: auto;
            }
            .teste {
                height: calc(100% - 20px);
                width: 100%;
                content: '';
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="teste"></div>
        <input type="text" id="texteeee">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I thought it was working but it isn't, keyboard is still above the content

Comment: oh, I see. Could you send me the link to your deployed version, to I can check, because as you know I can't isntall your website as an app from `http`

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem lots of times with websites. Usually [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) helps. The Element.scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element on which it's called into the visible area of the browser window.

You can bind it to `onFocus` event of the input.

```
 <input type="text" id="testee" onfocus="getElementById('testee').scrollIntoView()" />
```